# Android Studio 1.2.2 - New directory can't be created or showed or used

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles, android-file

what I am trying to do is to create a new directory (**styles**) in **res** directory so that I can store all my styles there and can manage my codes easily from there. I have done it in *Eclipse* many times in the time of android development.

So, what I am doing is given in the pictures -

Step 1 -

[image: Step 1]

Step 2-

[image: Step 2]

Step 3-

[image: Step 3]

Step 4-

[image: Step 4]

But the problem is the the new moved directory is created (it is seen from the top navigator - red marked), but it is not shown in the left navigator and the file shows error.

If I try to add a new directory, it also not showing the file directory in the left. So, I can't create a new directory in any way in **res** directory.

Is there any way to create a new directory what can be used in codes for managing codes in **res** directory or it is not supported in *Android Studio*?

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

At the left pane, you have a dropdown near the top in which you've currently selected **Android**. Click on it and select **Project**. Then you can see the entire directory structure with all your folders. Navigate to your res folder and create new directory like follows. `Your project > app > src > main > res > Right Click > New > Android Resource Directory`

Comment: "Is there any way to create a new directory in res directory or it is not supported in Android Studio?"

Comment: Yes you can create a new directory. Like I said, click on project and drill down to the res directory. Now right click on it and create a new folder.

Comment: If I create new directory, it is not supported an android studio.

My question is is it ever supported here?

Comment: Select Project structure instead of Android, then you can see it

Comment: If supported, how can I do it?

Comment: I can easily create a new directory just by right clicking on res and selecting create new directory. Why can't you?

Answer (score -1):

@Abrar Jahin, The answer by Bidhan A is the correct one. All you have to do for creating a new directory view from android to Project. Below the toolbar like CustomListView->App->....  You can see a tab saying Android click on it. There will be many options like Project, Packages, etc. Select Project, now you will get a entire structure as in Eclipse, Now create a folder, that should see you through.

Comment: No, that was not correct, because if I create any directory like that, it is not usable in codes.

So, if u know any way of using them in codes, please help me

Comment: What do you mean, not usable in codes. Firstly you cannot create a directory naming style and use it in codes. All you can do is create a resource file namely a xml file in the styles.xml and use it in you code. And if you want to create separate styles based on different API or different size then all you have to do is create a separate values-<your requirment> directory and under it create the file and call it in your code.